# How to round down a DateTime value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Location that can have Events. I want to have an `upcoming_events` method but want it to round down such that if someone looks at 10pm at night, it will show todays events. I have this:

```
def upcoming_events
  d=Time.new
  d.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
  l=Event.where('location_id=? and start_datetime>?',self.id, d)
end
```

I gets converted down correctly but in `d.strftime` but the query is:

```
SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (location_id=301 and start_datetime>'2012-06-20 02:49:23')
```

Any idea how to just get it to do '2012-06-20'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `strftime` does essentially nothing here, since it doesn't change the `d` object in any way.

Anyway, Rails provides the method [`beginning_of_day`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-beginning_of_day) on `DateTime` (as well as `Date` & `Time`) that does exactly what you want:

```
d = Time.now        #=> 2012-06-19 23:05:54 -0400
d.beginning_of_day  #=> 2012-06-19 00:00:00 -0400
```

So just change your code to:

```
Event.where('location_id=? and start_datetime>?', self.id, d.beginning_of_day)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually meant `"%Y-%m-%d"` vice `"%m-%d-%Y"` since you wanted `'2012-06-20'`. As such, try the following:

```
def upcoming_events
  d=Time.new
  l=Event.where('location_id=? and start_datetime>?', self.id, d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
end
```